# Unexpected result from PowerShell regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to identify errors in a log file. The application uses five uppercase letters followed by three digits followed by 'E' as an error code. The error code is followed by a non-word character. I was identifying cases with:

```
$errors=Select-string -Path "logfile.txt" -Pattern "[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{3}E\W"
```

However the remainder of the content now includes

```
ab1bea8a-a00e-4211-b1db-2facecfd725e.
```

Which is being matched by the regex and flagged as an error. I changed the regex to

```
\p{Lu}{5}[0-9]{3}E\W
```

(which I [expected to match five upper case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) characters), but why does it still match the non-error lower case pattern?

Comment: You may make `\p{Lu}` insensitive to the outer regex settings by placing it into a modifier group like `(?-i:\p{Lu}{5}[0-9]{3}E\W)`

Answer (score 4):

The "case-insensitive" regex flag is set by `Select-String`, which makes `\p{Lu}` case-insensitive, just as it does with `[A-Z]`.

Try adding the `-CaseSensitive` parameter to the command.

You can confirm this by running some .NET code, for example in LINQPad:

```
(new Regex(@"\p{Lu}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).IsMatch("a")
```

Comment: You may also include [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters) to the answer. The detail about `Select-String` case-insensitive matching  behavior is not easy find in the docs, although the `-CaseSensitive` option should hint at that by all means. Also, if one wants to mix case sensitivity options, it would be a good idea to add an example with modifier groups (not the case here, but would be good for generic cases).

Comment: Agreed, I thought about including that, but it wasn't a direct requirement of the question. And then I saw your comment, so that was taken care of anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell regular expression matching is case-insensitive by default. There are several ways for making matches case-sensitive, though.

- Add the `-CaseSensitive` switch when using the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-3.0) cmdlet:

  > **`-CaseSensitive`**
  >
  > Makes matches case-sensitive. ***By default, matches are not case-sensitive.***

  ```
  C:\> 'abc' | Select-String -Pattern 'A'

  abc

  C:\> 'ABC' | Select-String -Pattern 'A'

  ABC

  C:\> 'abc' | Select-String -Pattern 'A' -CaseSensitive    # ← no match here
  C:\> 'ABC' | Select-String -Pattern 'A' -CaseSensitive

  ABC
  ```
- Use the case-sensitive version of the regular expression [matching operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#matching-operators):

  > ***By default, all comparison operators are case-insensitive.*** To make a comparison operator case-sensitive, precede the operator name with a `c`. For example, the case-sensitive version of `-eq` is `-ceq`. To make the case-insensitivity explicit, precede the operator with an `i`. For example, the explicitly case-insensitive version of `-eq` is `-ieq`.

  ```
  C:\> 'abc' -match 'A'
  True
  C:\> 'ABC' -match 'A'
  True
  C:\> 'abc' -cmatch 'A'    # ← no match here
  False
  C:\> 'ABC' -cmatch 'A'
  True
  ```
- Force a case-sensitive match by adding a [miscellaneous construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/miscellaneous-constructs-in-regular-expressions) (`(?...)`, not to be confused with non-capturing groups `(?:...)`) with the inverted "case-insensitive" [regex option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#options) to the regular expression (this works with both `Select-String` cmdlet and `-match` operator):

  ```
  C:\> 'abc' | Select-String -Pattern '(?-i)A'    # ← no match here
  C:\> 'ABC' | Select-String -Pattern '(?-i)A'

  ABC

  C:\> 'abc' -match '(?-i)A'    # ← no match here
  False
  C:\> 'ABC' -match '(?-i)A'
  True
  ```